# Initial view on mobile (iPad etc) device with IsDlg=1

Tags: rendering

When displaying my sharepoint list on my iPad, I am using the IsDlg=1 parameter.

This works well, however, the view involves categories with an OOTB "twisty" on the left hand side.  The problem is that the twisty is too close to the left hand side of the screen.

Given that the display is very fluid for the IPad, I'm wanting to establish an initial margin parameter for the display.

Any suggestions on what kind of javascript rendering I can use to do this? I can change the s4-workspace field, but this makes a permanent change to the layout, whereas I just need an initial temporary setting.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The code I ended up using was

```
  if (mobileAndTabletcheck() == true) { 
        $("#globalNavBox").hide();     
        $('.ms-core-sideNavBox-removeLeftMargin').css('display', 'none');
        $('#contentBox').css('margin-left', '25px' );
    };
```

The mobile check function was drawn from
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381673/detecting-a-mobile-browser/

I did find an annoying feature of the iPad that if you double tapped somewhere in the vicinity of the text within the view, then it seemed to centre the whole display vertically. Perhaps this is just part of the safari function.